# webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest has delay before working

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

I would like to know why `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest` does not fire for about ~10 seconds when my app starts.

In my iOS using Cordova, I have a loading screen class that displays the loading view on app boot. The view intercepts the url load like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  NSURL* url = request.URL;
  // do something
  return TRUE;
}
```

But it takes time before the view begins to intercept the URL. I have confirmed this by placing a debugger in the method. It did not have this behavior before, and I haven't changed the loading screen class at all recently.

Any ideas? How might I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I did not set the delegate until later. `UIWebViewDelegate` needs delegate to work.

I my case, I had to do the following at the right time:

```
// ...
  myLoadingView.delegate = self;
// ...
```